# I can't add users from other group to my group

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I can't add users from other group to my group

I even tried to add 10 users but it doesn't work

It only works when user is a bot

> I am using Telethon 1.0.2 and Python 3.6.5

Result:

```
Updates(
        updates=[
        ],
        users=[
        ],
        chats=[
                Channel(
                        id=1201645703,
                        title='hello group',
                        photo=ChatPhotoEmpty(
                        ),
                        date=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1530507727),
                        version=0,
                        creator=True,
                        left=False,
                        editor=False,
                        broadcast=False,
                        verified=False,
                        megagroup=True,
                        restricted=False,
                        democracy=True,
                        signatures=False,
                        min=False,
                        access_hash=5823774251955326415,
                        username=None,
                        restriction_reason=None,
                        admin_rights=None,
                        banned_rights=None,
                        participants_count=None
                ),
        ],
        date=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1530554830),
        seq=0
)
```

Comment: Don't use StackOverflow to achieve spam goal

Comment: Do you want to take members of a group and add to your group?